# Remove the options to close questions on this site.

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, closed-questions

The way I see it, there's no real reason to close anything that's not offensive on this website.  People should utilize the [stuff-i-like] and [stuff-i-dont-like] tags to filter for stuff they consider "Lounge" material.

**Why can't this be a, "as a programmer, how do you feel about this" kind of a site?**

I'm really sick of seeing the same questions re-appear here that were already done to death on the original trilogy.

I'd get the most use out of people discussing subtleties, there are a lot of people on this site who have very good ideas who would I'd never find otherwise.  At work, I can't go into a chat room and ask these kinds of questions and I'll get 99% worse answers in a chat room.

This is a very special kind of website and I feel people are jumping to conclusions before considering the merits of questions!

I've participated on most of the SO websites since their inception, being much more of a learner than a teacher.  If my teachers continually told me not to ask any questions... well I'd be more of a bum than I am now.

Comment: You first said "there's no real reason to close anything that's not offensive on this website", but then I don't understand why you say the exact opposite: "I'm really sick of seeing the same questions re-appear here that were already done to death on the original trilogy"

Comment: Yeah, that's a little contradictory sorry. I'm sick of seeing them because they're the only ones that don't seem to get closed.   No one would ask them if they weren't so safe to ask.

Comment: Ah, yeah... But those do have some kind of value I suppose. For example, the "programming quotes" consists of a lot of programming quotes which have useful messages in them. And I guess it's not so easy to find such a programming quotes list reasonable fast on Google. Feel free to either elaborate some examples in your question and reasons why they should be banned, or create a response in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65437/adding-discipline-to-programmers-stackexchange-com

Comment: You aren't understanding the purpose of Pr.SE. See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: This may be the subjective site, but that doesn't mean it's the *argumentative* site. That's one reason. This also isn't intended to the "SO lounge."

Comment: This is also meant to be a community driven site, not a site driven by the tyranny of the minority who really don't like my jokes.

Comment: This site IS driven by the community, but some choose not to speak up nor vote nor do what they can do...

Answer (score 3):

It will not work out right...

If you are going to allow such questions, they will **result in useless bloat** on the site.
Not everyone wants to block a big set of tags to get the behavior of the site back to the way it is now.

If you **define a border** instead and close based on that border, the site will have useful questions.
This allows people to spent their tags on things they are interested in...

Comment: I think it's worth a shot.  It may be that the community votes with whether or not they choose to answer the question and the relative hotness mixed with the chosen tags will determine what you see first.  Almost everything gets an answer on Programmers, so why does so much get closed?

Comment: Yeah, it's up to the community... To respond on your last sentence: Because we want the site to be useful, if it's full of fun questions it will not have a list of useful questions on the front page which would scare new serious visitors. Remember, the sites were intended for experts, although others are welcome too as seen in the question were we form our FAQ: "professional and enthusiast programmers"

Comment: The community is not you, Jeff and the other people who close everything.

Comment: I didn't state that... What are you trying to say?